# Clustering Time Series with Multiple Features

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis

I am attempting to find states that have displayed similar employment trends over the past couple of years using clustering in python. I am having trouble figuring out the best format for the data and the best package to use/how to use it. My data has 21 features along with a state name and a month for each entry. Are there any packages or algorithms I should be using? I have found DTW a couple of times but seem to be struggling to use this.

Thank you!

[image: Example of data]

Comment: You can check out the following packages: pandas, matplotlib

Comment: @ParthShah Thank you for your comment! The data is already in a pandas dataframe, I am looking into actual clustering algorithms, and am planning on plotting once I can create these clusters.

Comment: I don't think [clustering](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-5-clustering-algorithms-data-scientists-need-to-know-a36d136ef68) would help. If you wish to analyze trends with multivariate data, you can a) compute a score, say average of all features for every state per month and then plot them b) plot each feature separately with all states and plot multiple graphs